# How does Jenkins lookup for maven repositories in Cloudbees?

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, cloudbees

I am facing regular issue with the way Cloudbees Jenkins lookup for maven repositories. Our project is still not mature so we use the private repository and an external SVN on Assembla. Usually jenkins would look into the public Cloudbees and our private repository to resolve dependency. But sometimes it stops in the public repo and fail to transfer the artifacts.

Edit: the triggered job projectA use a profile. This profile adds custom properties to complete the build.I have put them in a private settings.xml following this doc.

http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Sharing+Files+with+Build+Executors

so it seems this is deactivating cloudbees default profile.

One example with this job not finding a parent POM. Jenkins is able to deploy the parent POM to the private repository. It launches the second job (projectA)

```
Uploaded: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/1.2-SNAPSHOT/projectA-pom-1.2-20130416.155847-5.pom (5 KB at 79.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/maven-metadata.xml (285 B at 7.0 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (600 B at 9.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: https://repository-accountid.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/company/projectA-pom/maven-metadata.xml (285 B at 5.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Deployment done in 0.62 sec
Triggering a new build of projectA #12
```

The second build is supposed to use the new POM parent (or at least on already available). It searches in the public repository and stops there. Maybe it's a temporary problem with the Maven plugin (either Maven 2 jenkins plugin or Cloudbees maven plugin)

```
no change for https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/accountid.repo/projectA/trunk since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Failed to transfer Could not find metadata com.company:projectA-pom:1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in cloudbees-nexus-repository (http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/groups/public)
Failed to transfer Could not find artifact com.company:projectA-pom:pom:1.2-SNAPSHOT in cloudbees-nexus-repository (http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/groups/public)
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/projectA at hudson.remoting.Channel@2b842bd6:s-38976f5e
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:863)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:910)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:654)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1505)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenExecutionException: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.company:projectA-pom:pom:1.2-SNAPSHOT in cloudbees-nexus-repository (http://repo.cloudbees.com/content/groups/public) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 14, column 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [CloudBees Private Maven Repository](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository) wiki page? It is possible you need to configure a custom `settings.xml`.

Comment: hi, it seems the only viable solution: rewriting the cloudbees profile in the custom settings.xml. The issue remains we don't know the complete settings Cloudbees use for real.

Comment: I am adding here a more complete resolution: follow the steps in the link, put the settings.xml in your private webdav directory (/private/account/settings.xml). In your Maven command activate the profile id "cloudbees-private-snapshot-repository" and custom profile